# Jackson equivalent for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, json, jackson

I have used Jackson extensively on the Server side to convert from POJOs to JSON and was wondering if there is a similar library for Objective C/iPhone SDK and vice versa. Objective C does provide reflection so it should be possible to make something similar to Jackson.

Comment: Just to be clear since there may be a language barrier here; you want code to serialise objects into JSON automatically, based on their declared properties?

Comment: Yes, The other way around would be useful too because our server sends JSON encoded response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try [GoldenFleece](https://github.com/alexnauda/GoldenFleece), which converts between JSON and Objective-C objects using a convention-over-configuration pattern inspired by [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Comment: This is about a year too late for me and I notice the self-promotion but I appreciate the your effort writing this library. The current state of the art was painful.

Answer (score 2):

The [new iOS 5 APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) provide a great facility in reading/writing JSON.  These are essentially a rehash of the [TouchJSON library](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON/) which you can use in iOS 4.  While I haven't seen much out there that will generate POCO objects from an example payload, you can create classes that are just a facade for an `NSDictionary` instance that the aforementioned libraries will return.

For example:

```
@interface PBPhoto : NSObject {
    NSDictionary* data_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSDictionary *data;

- (NSString*) photoId;
- (NSString*) userId;
- (NSString*) user;
- (NSString*) title;
- (id) initWithData:(NSDictionary*)data;


@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "PBPhoto.h"

#define PHOTO_ID @"id"
#define USER_ID @"user_id"
#define USER @"user"
#define TITLE @"title"

@implementation PBPhoto
@synthesize data = data_;

- (id) initWithData:(NSDictionary*)data {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.data = data;
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString*) photoId {
    return [super.data objectForKey:PHOTO_ID];
}

- (NSString*) userId {
    return [self.data objectForKey:USER_ID];
}

- (NSString*) user {
    return [self.data objectForKey:USER];
}

- (NSString*) title {
    return [self.data objectForKey:TITLE];
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [data_ release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: It would be useful not to have to implement the getters for every property of every class. That's where reflection may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

That Objective-C provides reflection may be the understatement of the year, but a lot of stuff is exposed only by the low-level C runtime and therefore is a little obtuse.

Assuming you want to take an arbitrary object and turn it into JSON, probably the smart thing is to create an `NSDictionary` as an intermediary, then pass it off to `NSJSONSerialization` (or else construct the string yourself because all of the third party libraries are quite heavyweight owing to the burden of being able to deserialise).

So, for example:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryOfPropertiesForObject:(id)object
{
    // somewhere to store the results
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    // we'll grab properties for this class and every superclass
    // other than NSObject 
    Class classOfObject = [object class];
    while(![classOfObject isEqual:[NSObject class]])
    {
        // ask the runtime to give us a C array of the properties defined
        // for this class (which doesn't include those for the superclass)
        unsigned int numberOfProperties;
        objc_property_t  *properties = 
                     class_copyPropertyList(classOfObject, &numberOfProperties);

        // go through each property in turn...
        for(
              int propertyNumber = 0;
              propertyNumber < numberOfProperties;
              propertyNumber++)
        {
            // get the name and convert it to an NSString
            NSString *nameOfProperty = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
                                  property_getName(properties[propertyNumber])];

            // use key-value coding to get the property value
            id propertyValue = [object valueForKey:nameOfProperty];

            // add the value to the dictionary —
            // we'll want to transmit NULLs, even though an NSDictionary
            // can't store nils
            [result
                  setObject:propertyValue ? propertyValue : [NSNull null]
                  forKey:nameOfProperty];
        }

        // we took a copy of the property list, so...
        free(properties);

        // we'll want to consider the superclass too
        classOfObject = [classOfObject superclass];
    }

    // return the dictionary
    return result;
}
```

Then you can use `+ dataWithJSONObject:options:error:` on `NSJSONSerialization` with the returned dictionary.

To go the other way, I guess you'd use the key-value coding `setValue:forKey:` method, getting keys and values from a dictionary via `allKeys` and `valueForKey:`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is what I had in mind too but hoped that someone had done the hard work for me. I think I will use your example as a basis and whip something up myself